# How do I use Goalseek function in excel to generate a series?

Tags: excel, vba

am struggling with the application of goal seek function in excel. Am forecasting production for an oil well however we have a target cumulative production expected after say 20 years of production. I have produced table columns of monthly production rate and cumulative production. I would like to play (create sensitivity scenarios) with my expected cumulative production.

Can i use goal seek to change the production forecast profile per month by just changing the cumulative production at the end.

Also advise alternative functions should goal seek not be the right function for this task.

Appreciate your support

Comment: Goalseek doesn't work this way - it only allows you to change one value by setting your target. If you can find a way to link every month to a single "factor" that is used in the calculation of all months you may be able to do what you are trying but with your Goalseek you will technically only be changing that one field.

Answer (score 0):

This is really just an example of what @DanK has already mentioned. Say ColumnB figures are actual production (in black) and estimates (in blue). The estimates in this case computed as number of days in the month times the factor in D1 ("daily production"). To ramp up production so that the total cumulative production (in the example below, for 1-1/2 years, rather than all 20 as in the example above), presently estimated to be 115,620 units is instead 150,000 then Goal Seek might be applied so:

[image: SO25304268 example]

whereupon the D1 value (`200`) should change to `287` (and the total in B19 to `150,000`, and all the blue values change also). The principle should work if, say, June 2015 were calculated as 16*D1 rather than 30*D1 to allow for planned suspension of production. If that fortnight were an intervention to add production from another reservoir anticipated to be 100 per day then Goal Seek would not adjust "100 per day" but would adjust a new daily rate of 1.5*D1.